# When to use git commit -m and when to use git commit -a?

Tags: git

I am new to git bash. I moved from git GUI to become as sophisticated also. I noticed there's `git commit -a` and `git commit -m` bash commands for pushing commits. When should each be used or are they interchangeable?

I have been using `git commit -m` for all my commits.

Comment: They’re not for pushing, and they’re orthogonal.  Is there some part of their documentation you don’t understand?

Comment: This might help: `man git-commit`

Comment: or [git-commit](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit), when 'man' is not recognized as an internal or external command 

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's likely a bot question. It shows zero research and a nonsensical use of the `git` command with `-m` on its own, which requires a value.

Comment: I recommend *not* using `git commit -a`. It allows you to ignore Git's index aka staging area for a while, but ultimately you *must* learn what Git's index/staging-area is about, and it's wiser, in my opinion, to learn this very quickly. Using `git commit -a` is thus doing yourself a disservice.

Answer (score 2):

`git help commit` details the meaning of both of these options:

> -a, --all
>
> Tell the command to automatically stage files that have been modified and deleted, but new files you have not told Git about are not affected.
>
> […]
>
> -m <msg>, --message=<msg>
>
> Use the given msg> as the commit message. If multiple -m options are given, their values are concatenated as separate paragraphs.
>
> The -m option is mutually exclusive with -c, -C, and -F.

That is, they are completely orthogonal, and you can run `git commit` with either, both, or neither.

Comment: I was just about to says this :). See the documentation here: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit. Note. You can use both. I normally do, but I often use git commit -A instead of -a.

Comment: @JMB what is "git commit -A" ?

Comment: @TTT, my apologies. The capital 'A' is an option for git add. git add -A docs are "Update the index not only where the working tree has a file matching <pathspec> but also where the index already has an entry. This adds, modifies, and removes index entries to match the working tree.

If no <pathspec> is given when -A option is used, all files in the entire working tree are updated (old versions of Git used to limit the update to the current directory and its subdirectories)." from https://git-scm.com/docs/git-add